# VBA macro filtering

Tags: vba, excel

how to select records using multiple parameters in one sheet and then paste filtered values in second sheet.
Employee will be assigned "shared locker" according to their gender,department and building. E.g. locker no 7 should be assign to two employees who work in same department in same building and have same gender.

Comment: This is too broad a question. Could you supple a simple example of what you want? What do you mean exactly by using multiple parameters in one sheet?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Just turn on macro recording. You can filter the data on the multiple criteria using filter in Data Tab (Excel 2007 onwards). Once you are done, you can edit the macro generated vba code to suit your needs.

Comment: I have a list of New employees with their name & personal details, important part is their wing , floor and gender accordingly they will be assigned locker no. I have a sheet with details of all employees to whom lockers are allocated where as

Comment: I have a list of **New employees** with their name & personal details, important part is their wing , floor and gender accordingly they will be assigned locker no.                 
I have a sheet with details of all **existing employees** to whom lockers are already been allocated where as one column (**shared**)specifies if its shared or not now if the wing , floor and gender of new emp should be compared with whole records to find same wing , floor and gender and should be allocated a shared locker if available or new one accordingly